# Where do garbage flies come from?

Tags: entomology

I want to know the origin of those very small insects/flies which we see over kitchen garbage or when some surface is wet for some time. Where do they come from? Who actually reproduce them?

Comment: I suppose that they reproduce themselves. How a new garbage bin becomes infested with them is a good question - probably because they already live nearby, eithe rin other garbage bins or everywhere, but in less noticeable concentrations.

Comment: But I have seen them even when there are no nearby piles.

Comment: As I said - they are everywhere... not sure what is the question then.

Comment: Not spontaneous generation: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/97165/16866

Comment: “All things bright and beautiful all creatures great and small…”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q-> Origin of Insects/flies and Who reproduces them?
A-> Eggs laid by adult female flies.

Q-> Where do they come from?
A-> Nearby sewage, society waste-disposal areas, drainage systems.

The very common flies such as - *Musca domestica* and fruit flies often feed on rotten kitchen food, overripe fruits/vegetables, human excreta, animal dung. They prefer food that is either in liquidy or soluble in their saliva. Water is also required by them as they're also living creatures after all. Other food sources can be milk, sugar syrup, meat broth, etc.

Since dustbins are a food source for such insects, these are the perfect places for breeding as well (their babies also need nutrition). Female flies from near by sewage or locality waste disposal area often lay eggs on the home-based garbage and organic material. Eggs of flies are hatched within few hours and one can see a sudden increase in the number of flies around their bins.

In the daytime, when they are neither hungry nor breeding and prefer resting, that time they are seen in non-waste areas such as walls, floors, ceilings, clothes, etc. These resting places are nearby of their feeding places only.

For more info- Check https://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/resources/vector302to323.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Another major source for these flies is produce that is brought into a house, which may have fly eggs laid on it already.

While you aren't likely to eat maggot-filled fruit, it's quite easy for waste (e.g., peelings, cores, rinds) to end up sitting for long enough for the eggs to hatch in a trash can or down an imperfectly cleaned garbage disposal.